# How can I sort JSONArray by multiple criteria using Java?

Tags: java, json, sorting

Imagine you have a JSON file with information about users (including their *emails* (**stored in String**), *rating* (**stored in int**) etc). Mine looks like this:

```
{"data": [{"user": "trevor@mail.com", "rating": 3, "disabled": true},
{"user": "martin@mail.com", "rating": 14, "disabled": false},
{"user": "harry@mail.com", "rating": 14, "disabled": true},
{"user": "nevill@mail.com", "rating": 25, "disabled": true}]}
```

The goal is to sort this list by multiple criteria. The sorting criteria are also a part of a JSON file:

```
{"sort_by": ["rating", "user"]}
```

In our case the list should be sorted first by rating and then by user names (in case some users have the same rating).

I already created JSONArrays from both lists and managed to sort users by email. My **sort()** method looks like this:

```
private void sort() {
        JSONArray sortedJsonArray = new JSONArray();

        List<JSONObject> jsonValues = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            jsonValues.add(data.getJSONObject(i));
        }

        Collections.sort(jsonValues, new Comparator<>() {
            private String key = sort_by_array.get(0).toString();

            @Override
            public int compare(JSONObject a, JSONObject b) {
                String valA = a.get(key).toString();
                String valB = b.get(key).toString();
                return valA.compareTo(valB);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            sortedJsonArray.put(jsonValues.get(i));
        }

        data = sortedJsonArray;
    }
```

It works for sorting by Email, but doesn't work for sorting by int values, even when I try to turn them into String. Also it obviously doesn't work for sorting by multiple criteria.

**What should I change in my code so that it sorts the list correctly at least by one criteria which can be String/Integer or Boolean value? Thank you in advance.**

Comment: In your `compare` method you have to know the data type of the key field and handle the different comparison types.  Converting an `int` to `String` for comparison won't work.

Comment: So I have to write different methods for different data types?

Comment: No. Your comparator currently gets the field name to use, it also needs to get the data type and then switch...case on the datatype to perform the correct comparison.

Comment: Cast `Comparable aComp = (Comparable) a.get(key)` and `Comparable bComp = (Comparable) b.get(key)` and return `aComp.compareTo(bComp)`

Answer (score 0):

Implement a comparator class like this:

```
class KeyComparator implements Comparator<JSONObject> {

    private final String key;

    public KeyComparator(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(JSONObject o1, JSONObject o2) {
        Comparable v1 = (Comparable) o1.get(key);
        Comparable v2 = (Comparable) o2.get(key);
        return v1.compareTo(v2);
    }
}
```

Build a composite comparator like this:

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = new KeyComparator(sort_by_array.get(0).toString());
for (int i = 1; i < sort_by_array.size(); i++) {
    comparator = comparator.thenComparing(new KeyComparator(sort_by_array.get(i).toString()));
}
```

Then `Collections.sort(jsonValues, comparator)` should be good to go.